# How to implement jQuery mobile swipe event with persian datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, swipe, persian

I am trying to implement swipe event in a Javascript datepicker. The datepicker code is from this project: [Javascript datepicker](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/). So far is my code like this

```
jQuery(window).on("swipe", navigator: { onNext() });
```

However this does not work, I get this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

How can I implement jQuery mobile swipe event with the datepicker? Thanks in advance

Comment: The issue is with `navigator:{onNext()}` - you cannot place an object (nor its internal function call) there.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Ok thanks. I have solved the problem. The solution ended up something like this `jQuery( window ).on( "swipe", function() { window.pd[0].pDatePicker.navigator._prev();} );`